# Evaluate ContentControl without rendering to screen

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a datagrid and I'm writing a method to search through it to find some text. Practically all of my columns use a DataTemplateSelector, so in my search, I need to be able to take a DataTemplate, apply it to a ContentControl, and then find a TextBlock to get the text to see if it matches my search criteria. I'm trying the following but it's not seeming to produce any results. I also tried a FindName("layoutRoot" control) but that came back as null as well.

```
var control = new ContentControl();
control.ContentTemplate = dataTemplate;
control.Content = item;

var txtBox = control.FindChildren<TextBlock>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried VisualTreeHelper's GetChild()/GetChildrenCount() to enumerate all children?

Additionally, I believe you can set Initialized handler from XAML on a target control in a DataTemplate and from there subscribe to Loaded event (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going about this problem the right way. You should be getting your search items from a list that is hopefully in your viewmodel. And your grid's selecteditem should be bound to a property that you can set to the item that you found in your search. Let me know if you'd like me to flesh this out more for you with some code examples.

Comment: I was working on a generic framework with the grid, to allow a in-grid search over any of the items. Since what exists on the VM's items can be different with converters applied and other factors, searching through the VM wouldn't of helped.